# Why the close method is unknown when using map to close multiple files?

Tags: python

I have a use-case that resembles the following:

```
files = [open("foo1.pdf", "rb"), open("foo2.pdf", "rb"), open("foo3.pdf", "rb")]
# ... extract portions from the opened files using PyPDF2 and assemble a new PDF file
map(close, files)
```

Why I do that above? because while using PyPDF2 to merge multiple input PDF files into another file, if you close each input PDF you get empty pages in the output PDF. The input files have to stay open until the output PDF file is generated see https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/293

Results in the following error:

```
NameError: name 'close' is not defined
```

The following works but I'd like the less verbose code variation:

```
map(lambda file: file.close(), files)
```

I'd of course prefer the following instead:

```
map(close, files)
```

Comment: Your are not calling the `close` method, but some non-existing `close` function that would be used like `close(f)`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) which closes the files automatically for you.

Comment: @a_guest thank you so much! very nice comment :) plz promote to answer and I'll happily accept.

Comment: @SkyWalker The question is marked as a duplicate, so it cannot be answered at the moment.

Comment: Please vote to reopen, it makes no sense to mark as duplicate for that other one ... it's a bot close warmongering :D

Comment: You probably want to use an `ExitStack` context manager to ensure the files are closed in the event of an error. (Also, `map` doesn't return a list; none of the files will be closed until you actually iterate over the resulting `map` instance. Also also, don't use iterables where you should use a regular `for` loop.)

Comment: @chepner yes it has been commented right before, very good approach that solves my use-case cleanly.

Comment: Please vote to reopen, it has been faultily marked as duplicate.

Comment: a_guest gave the best comment/answer so please credits where credits due :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contextlib.ExitStack` to open your files and ensure that they are properly closed.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

names = ["foo1.pdf", "foo2.pdf", "foo3.pdf"]
with ExitStack() as es:
    files = [es.enter_context(open(f, "rb")) for f in names]
    # ... extract portions from the opened files using PyPDF2 and assemble a new PDF file

# proceed with the new PDF file
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `close` is, by itself, not a function, unlike `open`. Instead, it is a method of a file-like object.

If you want to programmatically close files, you can call `close` using the objects themselves.

```py
for x in files:
    x.close()
```

If you absolutely want to use `map`, you could use lambda function to do so, but I 'd recommend against that because `map` defines a generator, and hence it is unclear to the user which files are closed and which are open.

```py
map(lambda x: x.close(), files)
```